# Can i have distributed ledger among the members using hyperledger composer and fabric in a business network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

In my scenario i have one Business network with 20 participants. Can i have the distributed ledger among those 20 participants??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Composer terms the **Participant** is a data item on the Fabric Ledger.  An **Identity** can be issued to a Participant to enable a 'real Person' to interact with the business network.

Identities are issued by **Organisations**.  Composer builds on top of Fabric, and Fabric can be configured for **multi-organisation** (including 20 organisations).

Composer supports multi-organisation Fabrics.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the ledger is distributed among the members of the Business Network, however, you can add permissions through the ACL file to make sure that your data remains secure and only those members can access it for whom access is intended.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..                                                                                                                   But i deployed my business network into a single organization... so my question is can we have the same replica of that ledgure with all 20 participants.

Comment: just keep in mind that only organizations that have the ledger not participant.